# Testing node "Post" with Jest return an error

Tags: node.js, jestjs

When i try to test my node.js code with jest, it gives me a "Bad request" error and yet I can manually post some content into my database

How should I resolve this issue?

```
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../src/app')

test('should sign up a new user' , async() =>{
    await request(app).post('/users').send({
        name : 'jordy',
        email : 'jordy@example.com',
        password : '12345678'
    }).expect(201)
})
```

Output:

```
 PASS  test/math.test.js
 FAIL  test/user.test.js
  ● should sign up a new user

expected 201 "Created", got 400 "Bad Request"

  at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:268:12)
  at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:283:11)
  at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:173:18)
  at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 4 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.36s, estimated 11s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Comment: Do you have a `beforeEach()` hook at all that does any resetting?

Comment: refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322530/supertest-fails-to-test-repeated-post-request), it might helps you